# Chosen deselect on single selects and custom js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I got two selectlists. The second one displays child items of the first one. If i change the first selectlist i need to reset the second one, which works fine:

```
$("#main_selectlist").chosen().change(function()    {       
    $("#sub_selectlist").val('').trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```

Problem: The deselection button (X symbol which allready worked) on the first selectlist dissapears when i use the above js. How can i use the js above and the deselction feature together?

Comment: You are going to have to give more detail on this. Simple fiddle seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/UVEfw/2/

Comment: it was about singleselects. i had to do it like this: `$("#main_selectlist").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true}).change(function() ...` ... strange?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chosen allow\_single\_deselect is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908574/chosen-allow-single-deselect-is-not-working-as-expected)