# chosen allow_single_deselect is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

Below is my markup, i have empty option included in my markup

```
<select name="drop_down" id="drop_down" class="single">
  <option></option>
  <option value="First Choice">First Choice</option>
  <option value="Second Choice">Second Choice</option>
  <option value="Third Choide">Third Choide</option>
</select>
```

Any my js is like

```
$('.single').chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});
```

but i don't see blank option in drop-down after initialization, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8):

This normally happens if you are using a dynamic dropdown. The deselect will work fine after initialization. Once you empty the dropdown and fill it with new values and `chosen:update` it. You won't see the chosen `allow_single_deselect` option not working. If anyone looking for invisible chosen deselect option

Refer: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/1780

You need to add an empty option tag before you fill the drop-down will new values. If you miss an empty `<option>` before the actual drop-down values you will not see the deselect cross mark icon.

```js
$('#natureInput').chosen({
    allow_single_deselect:true,
    width: '50%'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<label for="natureInput">Nature</label>
<select data-placeholder="Choose a nature" name="nature" id="natureInput">
  <option />
  <option>Spring</option>
  <option>Winter</option>
  <option>Summer</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this post is old, but if any one still not able to figure this out. Here's what you need to do.
Documented: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html

> When set to true on a single select, Chosen adds a UI element which
> selects the first element **(if it is blank)**.

```html
<select class="chosen">
    <option value=""></option> <!-- required -->
    <option value="Batman">Batman</option>
    ...
</select>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".chosen").chosen({
        allow_single_deselect: true
    });
});
```

### Missing 'x'?

Make sure you have included the sprites in the 'same location'.

```
chosen
|-- styles
|   |-- chosen.jquery.min
|   |-- chosen.min.css
|   |-- chosen-sprite.png // image
|   |-- chosen-sprite@2x.png // image
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try to make the option not really empty but leave some whitespace in it, or even something like '(none)' or '(choose one).'

Answer (score 1):

oops my bad, the path to sprite image that shows close button on select was not correct due to which close button (cross symbol) was not displayed on drop-down and felt like blank is not working

Comment: I am also having the same issue. It works locally but not when uploaded to heroku. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` `/assets/chosen-sprite@2x.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the Chosen plugin before but I looked at the [website](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), the very first example has an empty option and the Chosen function gets rid of it when called. Also the allow_single_deselect option says that it will "add a UI element for option deselection" which doesn't mean it preserves empty options.

Comment: yes mine was not showing UI element for deselection, please see my answer for the mistake I was making

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an empty option both before and after updating the chosen.

Example:

```
//html
<select class="consultant_refer"><option></option></select>

//initialize
        $('.consultant_refer').chosen({width: '100%', allow_single_deselect: true})

//empty select but make sure to add another empty option
        $('.consultant_refer').empty().append('<option>')

//add other options
        consultants.forEach(function (data) {
             $('.consultant_refer').append($('<option>').val(data.id).text(data.name))
        })
        $('.consultant_refer').trigger('chosen:updated')
```